# Submit in-app purchase to itunesconnect always rejected, because it is too old productutil

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, in-app-purchase, xcode5.1

I'm working on an application with in-app purchase feature.

When using xcode 5.0.1 I managed to submit content (non-consumable) to itunesconnect.

After I updated to xcode 5.1, I still can submit to itunesconnect without any error (passes validation) but I always get emails from itunesconnect@apple.com:

> Dear developers,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "*app-name*". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>       The archive for In-App Purchase '*product_identifier*' is invalid. Productutil version 236 or later is required for In-App Purchase content delivery.
>       Once these issues have been corrected, you can redeliver your package.
>
> regards,
>      The App Store team

I've been looking productutil, but always find a dead end.

Is there anyone who has experienced this?

Where "productutil" is if you have downloaded?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may be an error on Apple's server end. I've run into the same situation last night (4/9/14) and this morning. I've been running Xcode 5.1 for a while now and have uploaded other IAP content packages with no problems over the past few months.

/usr/libexec/productutil doesn't appear to have a way to check the version, at least no way that I can find. I've even tried installing the latest Xcode GM seed (5.1.1) but that didn't help.

I've submitted an inquiry to Apple support. I'll report back if I get an answer.

Comment: I have the same issue, upload worked fine yesterday. Application Loader has the same problem, and so does iTMSTransporter. I've submitted an inquiry to Apple as I believe this is on their end. Will report back if they do...

Comment: Problem vanished. Had to change start_date in metadata.xml to yesterday.

Comment: Thanks All. Only change start_date? i will try, thanks

Comment: I tried again without changing anything and it worked this time. It looks like they must have resolved it on their end. Note that it did take a little while for the IAP status to change to "Ready to Submit".

Comment: Yes, I've also tried to submit without any change using xcode 5.1 and it's worked. I think this problem has been solved, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Productutil is part of the standard install for xCode located at :

usr/libexec/productutil

It's needed to build your app package. I think the best thing would probably be to completely reinstall xCode as I'm guessing you are using an older version or you've somehow retained an older version of the productutil file.